Open AI Whisper paper - how to interpret figure 2 robustness results
The Figure 2 of the Whisper paper is comparing WER on LibriSpeech clean-dev vs Average WER on other datasets. I believe clean-dev is the typo of clean-test dataset as specified in the Table 9 and Figure 2 is the plots of the Table.
I suppose Figure 2 is demonstrating robustness on out-of-distribution datasets on y-axis vs that on in-distribution datasets on x-axis (LibriSpeech test-clean).
The question is why the other datasets on y-axis listed in the Appendix A can be said out-of-distribution? Are the well known as such? And why the in-distribution vs out-of-distribution is ideal if it is one to one linear relation? Out of distribution results would be difficult to get them right, hence the linear line can be one to N?





